# BFS performance in searching shortest path

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, complexity-theory, breadth-first-search

There is a graph with up to **10 000 nodes** and each node can have up to **4 adjacent nodes**. Graph is **unweighted** and **undirected.** Task is to find **shortest path** from node A to node B. The path length is number of nodes visited in path. Can BFS algorithm find that path in less than **one second** and using less than **64mB** of memory?

Original problem is with grid(up to 100*100) and places that can be visited, start place, end place, and places that can't be visited. My first guess was to reduce that to finding shortest path in unweighted graph using BFS search. But, im not sure about speed and memory usage of that solution with large graphs.

Comment: 1 second? 64 mb? sorry, but if you not define the duration of a single operation, like the visit of a node, or the coding type (list, vector...) used for the graph, there is no answer for this question.

Comment: adjacency list for graph... i dont know duration of single operation. question is more about time complexity of bfs for that numbers of nodes and edges.

Comment: the time complexity of BFS is O(n) where n is 10.000, in the worst case you have to visit each node to find a path.

Comment: Yes it can, if you manage to cram your nodes + code + auxiliary structures into 64MB and buy a fast enough computer. This question cannot reasonably be answered out of context (programming language, implementation, machine the program runs on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Space complexity**

So you have 10 000 nodes and every node can be connected up to 4 other nodes. The max  number of vertices is 40 000. In [adjency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) it would require `O(|V|+|E|)=50 000` space in memory. Each variable would require 32 bit to represent it in the list. The maximum memory amount would be `40000*32/(1000*1000*8)=0.16` Mbytes. If [adjacent matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is used it would require `O(|V|^2)=40000*40000/(1000*1000*8)=200` Mbytes.

**Time complexity**

Wikipedia:

> The time complexity can be expressed as O(|V|+|E|) since every vertex
>   and every edge will be explored in the worst case. Note: O(|E|) may
>   vary between O(|V|) and O(|V|^2), depending on how sparse the input
>   graph is (assuming that the graph is connected).

So in worst case the time complexity would be `O(|V|+|E|) = 40 000 + 10 000 = 50 000`. With a modern computer that won't be a problem to be computed under 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

1s is imho ok (more like 0.001s -- 10^9 operations / second on modern computer).

Memory -- you need adjacency list representation array int[10000][4] + something to remember closed/used/unseen nodes >= 10000*4*6 = 240000 = 0.24MB. So it should be fine if my math is ok.